# multi-platform native libraries in C# nuspec

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, cross-platform, nuspec

We have a C# project (.net Core) which is cross-platform. It uses native libraries (C++), which are different for each platform.

We know that you can specify different frameworks in a single nuspec file, but this case is different:

- There will be a single C# DLL file
- There will be different native libraries (like a.linux.so and a.windows.dll)

We want be able to install only the libraries that are pertinent to a specific OS.

What is the recommended mechanism?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, make sure you are using SDK-based projects to ensure you get correct dependency trimming for target frameworks like `netstandard*` (instead of using a .nuspec file).

The goal is to separate your native runtime assets into a `runtimes` subfolder inside your NuGet folder so that the layout is:

```
\lib\YourManagedCode.dll
\runtimes\win-x86\native\some.dll
\runtimes\win-x64\native\some.dll
\runtimes\linux-x64\native\libsome.so
\runtimes\osx-x64\native\some.dylib
```

An example project file could look like this, assuming you already have runtimes folder:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="runtimes\**" Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

If you need to test locally, you can also add `CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"` to ensure the files are copied to the output. .NET Core should be able to resolve files located in runtimes directories for methods annotated with `[DllImport("some")]`.

The resulting NuGet package can be referenced from both .NET Core and .NET Framework projects. If some "RID-fallback" (e.g. `win10-x64` => `win-x64`) does not work on .NET Framework projects, make sure this project also references a recent version of the `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms` package (it provides NuGet with a graph of known values, has nothing much to do with .NET Core itself..).

Comment: What if the native images are too big and I want to separate them to different projects, but have one main NuGet that conditionally depends on all of them by OS?